# Get char * from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, char, loadlibrary

I have a problem. I have a function in my dll which is defined as below:

```
int function(char *inVal, char *outVal, int *retVal)
```

I successfully load my dll in a console application using LoadLibrary, and I call my function with function pointer:

```
typedef int (__cdecl *functionPtr)(char *, char *,int *);
```

then I pass my inVal to my function:

```
char * inVal = "input";
```

Now I want to get my outVal and retVal, I have got the retVal successfully but my outVal is NULL:

```
int retVal = 0;
char outVal[200] = {0};
```

then I call my function:

```
int return = functionLNK(inVal , outVal, &retVal)
```

any clue?!!

**EDIT 1:**

The code is as below:

```
int function(char *inVal, char *outVal, int *retVal) 

{

PKI_Buf inBuf, signBuf, pemBuf;

......


outVal = (char*)pemBuf.data;

//I check outVal in this point and it is not NULL

}
```

Comment: I checked the log in my dll and the outVal in my dll is not NULL

Comment: Did you mean `char outVal[200] = {0};`?

Comment: What about the function in the DLL? Are you sure it correctly changes the content of that buffer?

Comment: `char * inVal = "input";` is invalid in C++11. you should add a bit of `const`. or a buffer.

Comment: yes, I am totally sure because I checked the value of outVal in my dll with a log and that is not NULL.

Comment: @Amir: Can you show the code of the function in the DLL?

Comment: @Amir I bet you're not copying into the buffer but are just assigning to the pointer. Since the pointer is passed by value, you see no change on the outside. Not that it would matter because the pointer is a temporary object anyway (from converting the array name to a pointer to its first element).

Comment: @sftrabbit: Agree, that's my suspicion as well

Comment: @AndyProwl And now it's confirmed. Being psychic is great.

Comment: so what should I do??

Comment: @Amir Sounds like a strict work environment. No problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `function`. You pass `outVal` by value which means that the pointer you have inside the function is a copy of the one you passed in. Then you assign to that pointer with `outVal = (char*)pemBuf.data;`. All you've done is modified the copy. No change occurs on the outside.

This isn't the only problem with your approach though. You're also trying to pass a pointer to a member of an object that is about to go out of scope. `pemBuf` has automatic storage duration (because it is local to `function`) which means it will be destroyed when it returns. Then your pointer will be pointing at an invalid object.

Instead, what you want to do is copy the contents of `pemBuf.data` over to the array elements pointed at by `outVal`. You can do this with `std::copy` or `strcpy`. However, you have another issue which is you don't pass in the size of your buffer (and I don't know the size of the `pemBuf.data` array). Assuming you know how much to copy as `N`, however, you could do:

```
std::copy(pemBuf.data, pemBuf.data + N, outVal);
```

However, your code is very C-like - using C-style strings, output parameters, and so on. I recommend that you start using `std::string`.